# Операции с GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

1. Как узнать значения ячеек выделенной строки?
2. Как получать доступ к значению определённой ячейки (по индексам, по названию столбца)?
3. Как создавать программно строки и столбцы?

Короче, вопросов вагон, если кто знает, где найти толковых примеров использования GridView, то помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) вам на что?